Check updated items older than x
I want to make a filter for my colleagues showing Jira items which have not been updated for x-amount of days, but only working days.
The specifc amount of days will be static, but so far I not sure how many days are best for us.
I've tried my research but for the love of heaven and earth I do not get my head around that strange way of filtering out the weekends.
So basically an example:
Which items have not been updated for 15 working days?
As a bonus if someone could also explain the little steps along the way it would be much appreciated and help me to get a better understanding of that part.
I've tried it mostly by myself since I have a hard time understanding that weird constructed rule to exclude the weekends which unfortunately resulted in just not getting the exact items.
